# Merging hundreds of rasters in QGIS to create a basemap

Tags: qgis, merge, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I have a dataset of over 400 .tif-files, which I'm supposed to merge in QGIS into a single layer, representing a base map. These .tif files are pieces of a topography map (scale of 1 to 50000), and the file sizes are between 2 MB and 83 MB.

I'm relatively new to QGIS, and I have no idea what would be the smartest way to handle this (if there is any). Is it possible to create anything similar to ArcMap mosaic datasets in QGIS? I was specifically requested to find a way to do this in QGIS.

My research on the topic suggested that I could try to 1. build pyramids and then build a virtual raster or 2. use the merge function. Well, building pyramids for 400+ files seems painfully slow and manual.

Building a virtual raster without pyramids only gave me the error: "The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program". I have a write permission to the disk with the input and output locations, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Merge-function apparently only works for a few rasters at a time, not 400 of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Building a virtual raster without pyramids only gave me an error." we need to know what error you got.

Comment: The error: "The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program". I have a write permission to the disk with the input and output locations, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: sounds like you have some missing programs, I assume you are on windows? did you use osgeo4w to install, if so check you added the python modules

Comment: Please avoid statements like "file size is pretty huge" - get the file properties and tell us how many megabytes, or the typical resolution in pixels of height x width.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. 400 is not a large number of rasters to mosaic. I suggest you organize them into strips along the X axis, merge those, then merge along the Y.

Comment: Creating pyramids for all tifs in a directory does not need to be slow and manual, try something like `for %f in (*.tif) do (gdaladdo -r average -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR %f 2 4 8 16 32 64)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone and sorry for inconvenience (this is my first time here). @IanTurton can this be checked anywhere or should I just reinstall?

Comment: Also @Vince could you describe this in more detail, I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: the osgeo4w installer will show you want is and isn't installed if you run it again

Answer (score 3):

### Solved it.

I think the source of the error I got building a virtual raster was some sort of character limit in the Build Virtual Raster tool. After adding the input files (400+ of them) some of the text in the box at the bottom of the Build Virtual Raster tool window was cut off. Other people have also had [this issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130791/qgis-virtual-raster-insufficient-permissions).

I avoided this by using gdalbuildvrt through OSGeo4W Shell.

**Here's what I did:**

1. Used Translate tool to convert paletted .tifs into RGBs
2. Created a virtual raster from the RGBs (also added a forced CRS):

   ```
   gdalbuildvrt basemap.vrt *.tif -a_srs "EPSG:3395"
   ```
3. Built overviews for the virtual raster (similar fashion as user30184 suggested):

   ```
   gdaladdo -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES basemap.vrt 2 4 8 16 32 64
   ```
4. Additional step: Created a footprint/grid of all the .tifs, to get a look similar to ArcMap mosaic datasets (found this [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html)):

   ```
   gdaltindex footprint.shp *.tif
   ```

Also found [this site](https://astuntech.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ISHAREHELP/pages/14844053/Mosaic+thousands+of+raster+images) helpful since I've no previous scripting experience.